# How to throw a 404 in Laravel Form Request with custom Rule

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, rules

Usually Laravel's form request returns a generic `400` code on failing validation like this:

```
{
  "message": "The given data is invalid",
  "errors": {
    "person_id": [
      "A person with ID c6b853ec-b53e-4c35-b633-3b1c2f27869c does not exist"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to return a 404 if a request does not pass my custom rule.

My custom rule checks if a record exists in the DB:

```
class ValidatePersonExists implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return Person::where('id', $value)->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return "A person with ID :input does not exist";
    }
}
```

If I throw a `ModelNotFoundException` on failure of the `exists()` check, where can I catch it to respond with a friendly 404 response?

Here's my form request where I am using the rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'person_id' => ['bail', 'required', 'uuid', new ValidatePersonExists],
    ];
}
```

Comment: How you handling it in controller?

Comment: It's not reaching the controller. Laravel's form request performs validation, and it returns there.

Comment: Then try by validating your data in controller only using Validator and if validator fails you can send 404 status code.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify app/Exceptions/Handler.php, here is how i used it

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $status = method_exists($e, 'getStatusCode') ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500;
    //here im using translation, you can set your own message
    $response = [
        'errors' => trans("response.$status.response"),
        'message' => trans("response.$status.message")
    ];

    if (config('app.debug')) {
        $response['exception'] = get_class($e);
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        $response['trace'] = $e->getTrace();
    }
    //ModelNotFoundException statusCode is 0 so i need to pass it manually 
    if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException){
        $response['errors'] = new \Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag;
        $response['response'] = 404; // im using translation here
        return response()->view("errors.index", $response, 404);
    }
    
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

in my blade a simple translation message:

```
<p>{{trans("response.{$response}.response")}}</p>
<p>{{trans("response.{$response}.message")}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but I'm not 100% happy with it.

Basically I've created a class (ApiRequest.php) to extend Illuminate's FormRequest class, and in this ApiRequest class I'm intercepting the `IlluminateValidationException` and doing some logic on the failed validation, checking if the Request failed on my `exists()` rule. If it does, I'm changing the status code to 404:

Here's my class:

```
abstract class ApiRequest extends IlluminateFormRequest
{
    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \GetCandy\Api\Exceptions\ValidationException
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        $failedRules = $validator->failed();
        $statusCode = $this->getStatusCode($failedRules);

        $response = new JsonResponse([
            'message' => 'The given data is invalid',
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ], $statusCode);

        throw new IlluminateValidationException($validator, $response);
    }

    private function getStatusCode($failedRules)
    {
        $statusCode = 400;

        foreach ($failedRules as $rule) {
            if (Arr::has($rule, "App\Http\Requests\Rules\ValidatePersonExists")) {
                $statusCode = 404;
            }
        }

        return $statusCode;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone, if anyone has a better solution feel free to post an answer.

Comment: im using Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException for an api error validation and Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException for formData in failedValidation